# I need to change Phone format on contact object in xxx-xxx-xxxx

Tags: workflow

all 
I want to change phone format   which is default  (xxx)xxx-xxxx to xxx-xxx-xxxx on contact object   Phone field 
using workflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @ArjunSFDC you can create a workflow with your own criteria like is changed like and do a field update to custom field or standard.In field update select formula.

And the formula will look

IF(
 LEN(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( Phone , ".", ''),"-",""),"+",""))= 11,"("&
 MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( Phone , ".", ''),"-",""),"+",""),2,3)&") "&
 MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( Phone , ".", ''),"-",""),"+",""),5,3)&"-"&
 MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( Phone , ".", ''),"-",""),"+",""),8,4),""&
 MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( Phone , ".", ''),"-",""),"+",""),1,3)&"-"&
 MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( Phone , ".", ''),"-",""),"+",""),4,3)&"-"&
 MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE( Phone , ".", ''),"-",""),"+",""),7,4)
)

change that phone field with your filed.

May be it works for you.

Comment: I'm very happy it works for you.@ArjunSFDC

Answer (score 1):

There may more sophisticated way, as per me, add a field update to the workflow. And in the value field, put this formula.

```
SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Phone, ') ','-'), '(', '')
```

Let me know if it works. Thanks!

Comment: after   using your code  i got  output like this  7053993075  but  i need like  705-399-3075  like thanx

Answer (score 1):

Since we now have cascading workflow rules, it'd probably be easier to make it two rules.

Rule #1: Triggered when `ISNUMBER(Phone) = FALSE`

```
SUBSTITUTE(
  SUBSTITUTE(
    SUBSTITUTE(
      SUBSTITUTE(Phone, ')','')
      ,'(','')
    ,'.','')
  ,'+','')
,'-','')
```

Rule #2: Triggered when `LEN(Phone)=10 && ISNUMBER(Phone)` (= TRUE)

```
LEFT(Phone, 3)&'-'&MID(Phone,3,3)&'-'&RIGHT(Phone,4)
```